# Kivy: Open multiple python scripts

Tags: python, linux, user-interface, raspberry-pi, kivy

i try to open multiple Kivy Python scrpts on my Raspberry Pi 3. (Raspian Jessie)

I can start one script with command line `python kivy/examples/widgets/colorpicker.py`.
This works awesome.

But if i try to start a second Kivy application with a second Terminal i get the following error (I don't think that this will help much):

[image: I started the left script first]

For a short time i can see an empty (transparent) Windows with Title "Tutorial". Then it is closing.

Sorry for the stupid question (Kivy Beginner)...
Is this normal?

Comment: Please edit your question and the error you are getting

Comment: I have added the error

Comment: There might be a warning in the beginning of the run that can hint about the problem

Comment: Can you help me? 
Should i try a "clean" Raspbian installation?

Comment: kivy on the raspberry pi always maximizes the window to full screen. Why would you want to run 2 kivy apps at the same time? Also, in my experience it makes sense to switch to command line mode on the pi when working with kivy.